# Using d3.js + SoundCloud API - Need to show track titles

Tags: soundcloud, d3.js

I am using d3.js with the SoundCloud API.  I want to create a Bubble Graph that will display the track titles in the bubble.

They show in the HTML once the page is loaded in a "circle" element.  But I am not sure why they are not displaying.

and trying to create a Bubble Graph that will display track titles.

An example of what I'm doing can be seen here: 
http://butchershopcreative.github.com/ui-experiments/soundcloud/example/

The code looks like this:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: "7kIeyF5f2ETFo1fEWKwNQ",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8000/soundcloud/example/",
});

SC.get("/tracks?genres=dubstep&order=hotness", {limit: 100}, function(tracks){
  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 640)
      .attr("height", 480);
  var y = 500;
  var x = 1000;
  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(tracks) // data binds information to the circles
    .enter().append("circle").transition() // Added transitions
      .duration(1000)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d * scale); })
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke","#000")
      .style("stroke-width", "3px")
      .attr("class", "track")
      .attr("cx", function() {
            return Math.random() * x;}) // produces random x position
      .attr("cy", function() {
            return Math.random() * y;}) // produces random y position
      .attr("r", 50)
      .text(function(track) {
          console.log(track);
          return track.title; 
      });
});
```

Comment: I see the circles in your linked example (though the data doesn't seem to load every time - this may be an issue with the SoundCloud API). Have you updated your code since posting this question, and do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a `circle` element for text. You should be using an SVG `text` element, and I'd group the circle and text in a `g` element.

Like so (separating `enter()` and `update` code):

```
var bubble = svg.selectAll(".bubble")
  .data(tracks) // data binds information to the bubbles

bubble.enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "bubble");

bubble.append("svg:circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d * scale); })
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("stroke","#000")
  .style("stroke-width", "3px")
  .attr("class", "track")
  .attr("cx", function() {
    return Math.random() * x;}) // produces random x position
  .attr("cy", function() {
    return Math.random() * y;}) // produces random y position
  .attr("r", 50);

bubble.append("svg:text")
  .text(function(track) {
    return track.title; 
  });
```